# How to uninstall ffmpeg?

Tags: uninstall, ffmpeg, flv

How to uninstall ffmpeg?

After ffmpeg installed, FLV file format doesn't work.  Below are ffmpeg related files.

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_50.0.2661.102-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1117_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra.list
/usr/bin/ffmpeg
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/postprocessor/ffmpeg.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/postprocessor/ffmpeg.pyc
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs/libffmpeg.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/oxide-qt/libffmpeg.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstffmpegcolorspace.so
/usr/share/doc/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/gstreamer-ffmpeg.desktop
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply `sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg` just be aware that other software you use may depend on ffmpeg, so, read apt-get output carefully.

Comment: I excute "sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg".
But "Package 'ffmpeg' is not installed, so not removed" is shown.
How to uninstall ffmpeg?

Below are results
$ sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg
[sudo] password for freax: 
Package 'ffmpeg' is not installed, so not removed

Comment: Then you have'nt installed ffmpeg using the debian/ubuntu apt software. How you installed ffmpeg in the first place?

Comment: I installed ffmpeg via Firefox addon YouTube Video and Audio Downloader 0.5.2 option. After Firefox addon YouTube Video and Audio Downloader 0.5.2. installed, ffmpeg related files are installed.

Answer (score 0):

**FIX**

To get FLV functioning properly, try running this in your terminal:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

**WHY THIS WORKS**

The ubuntu-restricted-extras package contains audio codecs. Notice the word 'restricted.' This word is used by ubuntu because the package contains content that

**THE ISSUE**
First of all, according to your comments, `ffmpeg` is not installed. But I guess you know that much by now.

The issue here is that you replaced a codec; specifically your FLV codec. The `ffmpeg` FLV codec does work, it just probably is not compatible with the one that you were using before.

A codec has two main jobs: compression and decompression. To achieve these jobs, the programmer has to write an algorithm for each. The first has to give back a smaller version of the file. It is up to the programmer to decide how to do this.

This is important because **a set of identical files that are compressed by different versions (implementations) of the "same" codec are different.**

This is why your FLV files aren't working. Your new codec is trying to decompress files that it did not compress.

When a codec decompresses a file that it compressed, It should get back something really close to the original. (*How* close depends on the type of codec. For more info, research *lossful and lossless compression formats.*)

Note: When you switch out the decompression algorithm, the same thing should happen. You should get back something resembling the original. However, in the real world, standards aren't always followed.

In fact, in researching for this question, I learned that some codec formats are not even officially standardized. These are made up of just a basic idea and a free-for-all. I would guess that FLV is one of these. This is probably why it is not as popular as, for example, MP3.

Comment: Let me know if Ive left anything out. I typed this out days ago and never posted. Just found it buried deep in a rat's nest of open browser tabs. I skimmed through it and it looked okay, but I still can't shake the feeling that I left it unposted cuz I wasn't finished.,EDIT:  Now I know. Q is from 2016. Oops. Answer is still helpful in 2021 though, so I will leave it up. I am such a doofus.